# Cannot access bean when deploying ejb module and web module separately?

Tags: jboss, ejb-2.x

I was testing an EJB 2.x application. I created 2 module **separately**:

**EJB module**: contains a simple stateless session bean

**Web module**: contains a single servlet page to lookup EJB module.
I was using `Jboss 4.2.3`.

**First**, I deployed the EJB module and the deployment went well.
**Second**, I deployed the web module and the deployment went well.

Then I used the following code to look up the EJB module:

```
Context c = new InitialContext();
Object o = c.lookup("HelloJNDI"); // Line 1
HelloLocalHome rv = (HelloLocalHome) o; // Line 2
HelloLocal local =  rv.create();
```

The lookup went well (`Line 1`), but `Line 2` produced a class cast exception.

Then I test the above code in 2 scenarios:

1. I packaged the EJB and the Web module into a single `EAR module`. Then, deployed this `EAR` module in `JBoss 4.2.3`, and the lookup code above worked like a charm.
2. I tried to use `JBoss 5`, and even deployed the EJB module and the Web module separately, the lookup code above worked great.

So, why when I deployed the 2 modules separately in JBoss 4, things did not work out? I use local JNDI lookup only because the 2 modules were deployed in the same container.
Was I missing something or this is a flaw in JBoss 4?

Comment: What is the full stack (or at least the message) of the ClassCastException?  What are the values of o.getClass(), o.getClass().getClassLoader(), and HelloLocalHome.class.getClassLoader()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code instead of your cast:

```
HelloLocalHome rv = (HelloLocalHome)javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(o, HelloLocalHome.class);
```

If that does now work, then you have the infamous classloading problem. (One of the reasons JBoss 5's default server uses a different classloading mechanism). Easiest is to indeed place them in a single EAR (so the Home and remote classes are loaded once). The Home interface class in your web application is loaded by a different classloader than the one being returned by JNDI.

You can also remove the interfaces from your WAR file's classes or lib dirrectory